# How can I extract probabilities from my data?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

Suppose I have a series of IID RVs $\theta_1, \theta_2, \dots , \theta_J$ all taking values between $0$ and $\pi$.

Suppose further that the distribution is unknown.  Is there anyway I could extract probabilities, assuming J is sufficiently large, even though I don't know the distribution?

One thought I had would be to make a histogram and somehow compute probabilities through that, but that doesn't seem like a good way to go about doing that.

Answer (score 1):

If $F$ is the unknown distribution that gives rise to $\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_J$, then it's reasonable to approximate it with its empirical counterpart 
$$
\hat{F}(x)=\frac{1}{J}\sum_{j=1}^J1(\theta_j\leq x),\quad x\in[0,\pi].
$$
By the Kolmogorov law of large numbers, $\hat{F}(x)$ converges almost surely to $F(x)$ as $J\to\infty$. Then probabilities that depend on $F$ can be approximated by replacing $F$ by $\hat{F}$ wherever the former occurs.

Comment: Here, is $F$ the cdf or the pdf?

Comment: @user3600497 CDF